# Wireshark returns error on filters from Windows command prompt

Tags: networking, wireshark

It works when i use GUI with the following filter `http.request.method == "GET"` but when i run tshark is aways returns error

tshark -i 1 -Y 'http.request.method == "GET"'
tshark: Syntax error near "http.request.method".

How can I run tshark from command line and filtering for http.request.method == "GET" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the single quotes around the display filter and put the whole filter in double quotes

```
tshark -i 1 -Y "http.request.method == GET"
```